# Serializing a variables_map

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization, boost-program-options

How do I serialize/deserialize a boost::program_options::variables_map?  I can't find an already implemented serialize function, and I don't know what functions in variables_map I can use to extract and reassemble the map.

Comment: I wrote my own serialization, but it's having trouble deserializing the boost::any's in the variable_value.

Comment: ok, i give up.  my attempt is here: http://pastebin.com/jBkA3G9x

Comment: What about this : http://pastebin.com/jBkA3G9x/

Comment: did you mean to link to my attempt?

Comment: Sorry I did not see your link, I guess it it did not work, best way it to inherit the class and implement `serialize` `unserialize` functions.

Comment: how does inheriting help?

Comment: inhertiing helps in many ways in your case you need to extend the class, and add some feature or functions like serialize / unserialize to it.

Comment: but `boost::serialization` lets me add serialize/unserialize non-intrusively.  why do i need to extend the class?

Comment: Ok then use `boost::serialization` this is a good link about it : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html

Comment: I'm already using `boost::serialization`.  But I can't serialize a `boost::any` with it.

Comment: Why you can't? are the functions implemented ? 
Try to follow this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351299/boost-serialization-via-base-pointer-to-derived-class

or this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490245/virtual-functions-and-template-clash

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you found out that `boost::program_options::variables_map` derives from `std::map` so you can use its serialization (but see the warning later on this).  If the only remaining problem is serializing the `boost::any` values it contains then you're almost there.

You can't serialize an arbitrary boost::any because it doesn't really know how to manipulate what it holds.  However, if you know and can enumerate the types used by your application, then serialization is possible.  For example, if you know that the `boost::any` value is always a string or an int, then something like this should work.

To serialize (value is a `boost::any`):

```
if (value.type() == typeid(int)) {
   ar << std::string("int");
   ar << boost::any_cast<int>(value);
}
else if (value.type() == typeid(std::string)) {
   ar << std::string("string");
   ar << boost::any_cast<std::string>(value);
}
```

To deserialize (value is a `boost::any`):

```
std::string type;
ar >> type;
if (type == "int") {
   int x;
   ar >> x;
   value = x;
}
else if (type == "string") {
   std::string x;
   ar >> x;
   value = x;
}
```

Obviously you can use more efficient type tags than "int" and "string" in your serialization stream, but this gives you the basic idea.

Edit: `boost::archive` is picky about const references so what I wrote above doesn't quite compile.  This does, and it worked for a very simple test:

```
enum {
   TYPE_int,
   TYPE_string,
};

namespace boost {
   namespace serialization {

      template<class Archive>
      void save(Archive& ar, const boost::program_options::variable_value& value, unsigned int version) {
         const boost::any& anyValue = value.value();
         if (anyValue.type() == typeid(int)) {
            int type = static_cast<int>(TYPE_int);
            int typedValue = boost::any_cast<int>(anyValue);
            ar << type << typedValue;
         }
         else if (anyValue.type() == typeid(std::string)) {
            int type = static_cast<int>(TYPE_string);
            std::string typedValue = boost::any_cast<std::string>(anyValue);
            ar << type << typedValue;
         }
      }

      template<class Archive>
      void load(Archive& ar, boost::program_options::variable_value& value, unsigned int version) {
         boost::any anyValue;
         int type;
         ar >> type;
         if (type == TYPE_int) {
            int x;
            ar >> x;
            anyValue = x;
         }
         else if (type == TYPE_string) {
            std::string x;
            ar >> x;
            anyValue = x;
         }

         value = boost::program_options::variable_value(anyValue, false);
      }

      template<class Archive>
      void serialize(Archive& ar, boost::program_options::variables_map& value, unsigned int version) {
         // Probably works but is sloppy and dangerous.  Would be better to
         // deserialize into a temporary std::map and build a variables_map
         // properly.  Left as an exercise.
         ar & static_cast<std::map<std::string, boost::program_options::variable_value>&>(value);
      }
   }
}

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE(boost::program_options::variable_value);
```

There are a couple possible issues with this code.  The first is in `load()` for `variable_value` - the last statement makes a `variable_value` from a `boost::any` and I wasn't quite sure what that `bool` argument did (you may need to serialize whatever that `bool` represents).  The second is that you may or may not get a consistent `variables_map` by just casting to a `std::map` reference and deserializing.  It would be safer to deserialize into a real `std::map` and then build the `variables_map` from the `std::map` contents.

Comment: What an answer, so comprehensive... +1.