# How to serialize an object that keeps pointers to other objects in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, serialization, boost

I'm looking for a way to serialize a large complex object in C++. I've been thinking of using boost serialization api, but I'm not sure if it's even possible to serialize an object implemented in such a way.

In my program I have the following objects:

```
typedef map<float, float> SignalData;
typedef pair<float,float> TimeValuePair;

class SignalDatabaseNG : public SignalDatabase
{
   (...)
   private:
      vector<SingleSignal *> all_signals;
   (...)
};

class SingleSignalAsStdMap: public SingleSignal{
   private:
       SignalData * signalData;
   (...)
};

class IntegrationComparator : public Comparator {
   private:
      map<SignalData *, float> * preComputedIntegrals;
   (...)

   public:
       IntegrationComparator();
       float compare(SignalData *a, SignalData *b);
       void preComputeIntegralsForAll(SignalDatabase * database);
   (...)
 };
```

SignalDatabase is a class whose most important role is to keep all the data needed for the program. The signal is represented as a map of two floats (time and value), and all the signals are kept inside a vector of such maps.

It's being filled with data in the following way:

```
SignalDatabaseNG * signalDatabase = TestConfiguration::getSignalDatabase();
IntegrationComparator * integrationComparator = new IntegrationComparator();
integrationComparator->preComputeIntegralsForAll(signalDatabase);
```

`TestConfiguration::getSignalDatabase()` returns a database object that contains the data needed for the computation of integrals (its read from text files at the beginning of the program runtime). Then, `integrationComparator` object is created and `preComputeIntegralsForAll(SignalDatabase * db)` is called, which performs the computation. In the end, `map<SignalData *, float> * preComputedIntegrals` inside `integrationComparator` is filled with data.

This computation of integrals takes a huge amount of time (it's about 60 seconds for 10 signals, and I need to have it computed for ~220000 signals).

I'd like to be able to run it once, then serialize it, and then reuse it with each program run (the data doesn't change often, so it would be a huge time saver).

The problem is that the map maps the pointer to a signal object to the integral value. But, in the next run, the database would be created from scratch and all the addreses inside pointers would change.
It's possible to serialize both signal database and precomputed integrals database, but then there's also no guarantee that after de-serialization signals in the database would be at the same places in the memory, so the pointers inside integralsComparator would also be completely wrong.

Has anybody got any idea how such serialization could be done (preferably, without having to rewrite the whole structure of classes)?

Comment: You really love them pointers, don't you?

Comment: It's probably because I feel most comfortable with java, and there everything is a pointer, which I see as a good thing. But in this case, the data sums up to ~5GB, would you expect me to pass everything by value?

Comment: I would expect you to pass by reference when you need to refer to an object. I would expect you to pass by value when you need a copy.  I would expect you to store smart pointers when you need dynamic allocation.  And I would expect you to store objects when you need objects.  And if passing large objects around by value scares you, read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision), and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Move_semantics#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors) and [this](http://joseluisestebanaparicio.blogspot.com/2010/06/want-speed-pass-by-value.html).

Answer (score 3):

boost serialization can deal with pointers to objects, even when they are [polymorphic](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#derivedpointers). The library will serialize the object pointed to (and register its type) and when reading from the archive will create a new instance of the object, deserialize and fill the pointer.

The [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351299/boost-serialization-via-base-pointer-to-derived-class) go into some of the details of what you would need to do to help the library in recognizing the derived classes when deserializing.

This will also work with shared_ptrs and other smart pointers (hint, hint).

Additionally, boost serialization can also [track your objects](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#objecttracking) for you, so that when two pointers to the same object are serialized, the object is serialized only once.

The interesting part in your design is that you are using pointers as keys of a map. That may work (in some ways a map is just a container of pairs), but I have never tried that with boost serialization.

Comment: In this case there's a map inside another map. So in one way it's a structure of 3 floats, 2 of which are the key, and the third one is the value. But the map that's being used as the key, is used in many other contexts inside the program, it's a sort of a main data repository for various classes to use, so it cannot be embedded inside one of those classes, it has to be 'only' referenced by it.

Comment: @NataliaZoń: Some comments could be made about your code and about what seems to be overuse of pointers. In my answer I was trying to stick to the serialization issue. The "bad smell" statement may be a distraction from that answer, so I'll change that statement to something more neutral.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to serialize and deserialize objects held by pointers and collections of pointers using boost serialization. See [Tutorial/Pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#pointers).