# Virtual functions and template clash

Tags: c++, templates, abstract-class, boost-serialization

I have an abstract base class for a pointAccumulator. This abstract base will be filled out with methods such as a function that returns mean of all the points. An example of these two classes is shown below:

```
class lala {
public:
    virtual someFunctions = 0;

    virtual bool isEmpty() = 0;
};


class lalaLower : public lala {
public:
    lalaLower(){}
    ~lalaLower(){}


    someFunctions

    template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & heights_;
    }

protected:
    std::deque<double> heights_;
};
```

As you can see in the code I would also like to use boost serialization in to save these types. Now using a factory pattern i believe that you call the pointAccumulator types like this:

```
lala *a1 = new lalaLower();
```

My problem is that the templated serialize method will not be accessible if I call it this way. Also I cannot have the templated class in the abstract class as this is not allowed by c++. Is there a way to get around this?

Edit:

I have considered the non-intrusive method for serialization but that requires heights_ to be public which is not ideal, nor is it good programming style. I thought potentially a method using friend classes or functions could penetrate the class with access to the variables while still keeping the base class abstract? can anyone explain how this would work?

Comment: This is a fundamental problem; virtual functions are about runtime selection based on type; templates are about compile-time generation of code based on type; you cannot generate code at compile-time if you don't know the type until run-time.

Comment: Yep, I stated that in the question. So i guess the question is now, is there a better or a different way to go about it?

Comment: I believe this is the fundamental topic discussed in the book
"Modern C++ Design by By Andrei Alexandrescu". 
Read that if you want a good understanding of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using friend classes or functions is a good solution, you could add new class like Serializor

here is a example of friend function

```cpp
class Serializor;
class meanAccumulator : public pointAccumulator 
{ 
public:     
meanAccumulator(){}     
~meanAccumulator(){}     
double getHeight();     
void addHeight(double Height);     
void setHeight(double Height);     
bool isEmpty(){ return heights_.empty(); }      

protected:     std::deque<double> heights_; 
friend int Serializor::Func1( Serializor& );

};
```

refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahhw8bzz.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I believe you cannot do it without wrapping `Archive` type parameter into polymorphic hierarchy this way or another.

It seems though that `Boost.Serialization` [does it for you](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/archive_reference.html#polymorphic).

Comment: +1 It would have been very surprising if Boost hadn't thought about and solved this problem already!

Comment: I am a little confused about this solution. It does say that using polymorphic methods stop the need for template's. However, in the given example, demo_polymorphic_A.cpp, and the associated h files, the class A (ie the class being serialized). uses templated serialization anyway? EDIT: I get it, the template is still there but they use a cpp file to explicitly instantiate it. As a question, how can i use this to solve my problem wouldnt i still need a template function in my abstract class to use this solution?

Comment: I guess the examples themselves are actually broken.

Comment: No I dont think they are, they maybe are just not to solve this problem rather then the problem of delayed compile time or something like that?

Comment: In this case you are left with a scary option of implementing your own hierarchy for Archive type argument.

Comment: Polymorphic archives are not what the OP needs.  OP needs to read the documentation I tried to cite them, but got my face slapped for it, and follow the Boost.Serialization techniques for serializing derived types and registering those derived types with the archive.  Much has to be done and it's all in the link I tried to provide, within the documentation for Boost.Serialization.

Comment: That does sound scary, I might have a go at implementing it in a similar way to the given example before I try that.

Comment: @CrazyEddie, the reason you got slapped (I didn't agree with removing the answer though) is because you just provided the main page for the boost serialization webpage. Could you be a little more specific about where you are talking about?

Comment: Also I think you might misunderstand the problem, deriving from the class would be fine if my base class wasn't an abstract type. I cannot put a templated type in an abstract class, it is forbidden. Therefore I cannot derive it in my child classes. If i implement them explicitly and then call the class as I would in a factory ie. pointAccumulator * A = new meanAccumulator(); then the serialize function would not be accessible unless I cast A to a mean accumulator, which is not really good programming practice.

Comment: Have no idea what are you talking about know. I'm talking about 1) un-templaizing `serialize` method by changing its type variable `Archive` to classical OO hierarchy; 2) making `serialize` virtual and moving it to the base class.

Comment: Sorry Alex I was talking to crazyEddie. That is correct and is what I am trying to do.

Comment: @CrazyEddie Actually you gave a link to the boost serialization page. Something that I have found and read at the beginning of the question. You didnt clarify what your solution was or how to get there from that page. Your comment above about serializing derived types gave a better indication of what you meant but is not the solution to the problem. So perhaps your answer was incorrect anyway. I appreciate your help but perhaps you should give more detailed answers. As a note this is not a forum for broadcasting your feelings, so you should probably try to keep things more professional.

Comment: Unfortunately This solution does not work, You cannot make a virtual template function. There may be no way around this.

Comment: Yes, but you _can_ have a template _class_ with virtual functions. Something among these lines: `struct Base { virtual void f() = 0; }; template <class T> struct Derived : Base { virtual void f() { /* */ } };`

Comment: That is correct but you cannot have a templated class with templated virtual functions. It is illegal for a templated function to be purely virtual. I think that your solution requires the function to be templated even though you dont have to build templated code at compile time because it is already instantiated

Comment: It doesn't look to me like you have to support anything but the polymorphic archive interface: `namespace boost { namespace archive { class polymorphic_iarchive; class polymorphic_oarchive; } }

struct A {
void serialize( boost::archive::polymorphic_iarchive & ar, const unsigned int file_version) { ar & data;} /* or '= 0;' in the abc */
boost::archive::polymorphic_oarchive & ar, const unsigned int file_version){ ar & data;} /* ditto */ int data; bool operator==(const A & rhs) const {return data == rhs.data; } A() : data(0){} };
`

Answer (score 1):

As you may know that `template`s and `virtual` methods don't go hand in hand.

I would suggest to remove the `meanAccumulator::serialize()` method and add into `class pointAccumulator` body and call the `virtual` functions inside wherever they are needed.
You can also think of passing a handle of derived class and call the method with that.

```
class pointAccumulator {
public:
  template<class Archive, class Derived>
  void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version, Derived &derived)
  {                                            // optional ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // call virtual methods to derived from here
    // optional: for non-virtual method, you can use derived class handle
  }
};
```

The only thing which you need to take care is that, whatever non-virtual methods you call inside `serialize()` using `derived` handle --> should be of same name in all the children classes from `pointAccumulator`, irrespective of what they do inside.

Comment: I was hoping to keep the class pointAccumulator purely virtual, so that the factory pattern can still work. I also need serialization. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: @Ben, what is the problem if you keep few function non-virtual ? The `pointAccumulator` will still remain abstract. I feel the way I suggested will make the things easier. I don't find any other way.

Comment: I will give that a go, but having purely virtual functions is the better programming technique for factory classes I think. I was really hoping to keep it virtual.

Comment: @Ben, I believe you should adapt the technique which is better suited for your needs. That's why c++ is made flexible than ideological.:)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I'll make my comment an answer:

```
~/src/snips$ cat serializer-demo.cc 
#include <boost/archive/polymorphic_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/polymorphic_oarchive.hpp>

typedef boost::archive::polymorphic_iarchive bpi;
typedef boost::archive::polymorphic_oarchive bpo;
typedef const unsigned int cui;

struct ABC
{
        virtual void serialize(bpi &ar, cui v) = 0;
        virtual void serialize(bpo &ar, cui v) = 0;
};

struct A : ABC
{
        void serialize(bpi &ar, cui v ) { ar & data; }
        void serialize(bpo &ar, cui v ) { ar & data; }
        int data;
        bool operator==(const A & rhs) const
                { return data == rhs.data; }
        A(int data=0) : data(data) {}
};

#include <sstream>
#include <boost/archive/polymorphic_text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/polymorphic_text_oarchive.hpp>

#include <boost/archive/polymorphic_binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/polymorphic_binary_oarchive.hpp>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const A a(1);
    const ABC &abc = a;
    A a1;
    ABC &abc1 = a1;
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        {
            boost::archive::polymorphic_text_oarchive oa(ss);
            boost::archive::polymorphic_oarchive & oa_interface = oa; 
            oa_interface << abc;
        }
        {
            boost::archive::polymorphic_text_iarchive ia(ss);
            ia >> abc1;
        }
    }
    if(! (a == a1))
        return 1;
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        {
            boost::archive::polymorphic_binary_oarchive oa(ss);
            oa << abc;
        }
        {
            boost::archive::polymorphic_binary_iarchive ia(ss);
            boost::archive::polymorphic_iarchive & ia_interface = ia; 
            ia_interface >> abc1;
        }
    }
    if(! (a == a1))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

~/src/snips$ make -B serializer-demo
g++ -o bin/serializer-demo --std=c++0x -g -O -march=native -pipe -Wall -Wno-parentheses   -lboost_serialization  serializer-demo.cc
~/src/snips$ type -pa serializer-demo
./bin/serializer-demo
~/src/snips$ serializer-demo
~/src/snips$ echo $?
0
~/src/snips$
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there a way to use this in the case that the serialize method will be called inside of a higher class serialize which uses regular templated methods? At the moment I am getting a lot of compile errors because the template "Archive" is default set to text_iarchive.

Comment: @Ben The non-templated serialize takes a polymorphic {i,o}archive, so that's what you have to provide. You can construct archives on streams, I'm about to game w/ my kid so you get to hunt up whether you can casually construct archives on other archives and have them intermix the way you want.

Comment: I am using polymorphic_binary_(i/o)archives when I build the code but it still compiles saying that there is no matching function for text_(i/o)archive and binary_(i/o)archive for every time i use the method.

Comment: Look at the lines like `boost::archive::polymorphic_iarchive & ia_interface = ia; ia_interface >> abc1;` above: the sample code is already doing what you're asking for.

Comment: I have implemented it correctly now and it builds fine. But when i run it it says unregistered class - derived class not registered or exported. If I try to export it I get all those crazy compile errors I was talking about above.

Comment: Also why do you use the interface for one direction in text and the other in binary?

Comment: That's their sample, it exists just to show different ways to do things not to do anything sensible in itself.  I'm trying to diagnose trouble in code I can't see now, so do think about that some, but it seems to me your trouble might be that the templates don't differentiate between the iarchive's and the oarchive's.  Make the main call a helper based on the `is_saving` value.  For the registering, I"m going to refer you to the docs, this is getting beyond answering-a-question territory.

Answer (score 1):

So I have an interesting way of faking virtualism for templated functions. [Faking a virtual templated function c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575457/faking-a-virtual-templated-function-c)

The basic motivation might be applied here if you need this enforced in the hierarchy, but you can utilize boost meta programming library to allow a run-time solution for this problem.